# regex, string contains several specific characters, exactly k times

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of words, and I want to filter them based on specific characters and the number of time each character **has** to appear, in no particular order.
All other characters can appear any number of times.
For exmaple,

Filter all the words that contain the letter "a" exactly 1 time, and the letter "b" exactly 2 times.

"bbad" or "bxab" should match, "bbaad" should not.

I currently arrived to this regex which doesn't specify the number of times each character appears:

```
\b(?=[^\Wa]*a)(?=[^\Wb]*b)\w+\b
```

I tried:

```
\b(?=[^\Wa]{1})(?=[^\Wb]{2})\w+\b
```

but that doesn't work.
Another thing is I want the regex to be somewhat modular, because the desired characters are determined in running time.

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: @KellyBundy Hello, thank you for the comment! I changed most of the question and added a specific and clear example. I thought regex would be most suitable for this but if I'm wrong I'm happy to implement more elegant solution.

Comment: @KellyBundy damn I'm bad at being specific. Yes, "bbxa" should match. Unspecified characters can appear any number of times.

Comment: Something like Cary's regex might work, but `s.count('a') == 1 and s.count('b') == 2` is much simpler and probably much faster, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dunno if you're set on using regex, but I prefer to use *normal* logic as it's easier to read.

The code below does what you want. Pass it a list of lists or tuples with the letter to search for, and the amount of times it needs to occur.

**NOTE:**
See Kelly Bundy's commment below for a better version of mine..

```py
def filter_words(text: str, filters: list) -> bool:
    result = True
    for character, frequency in filters:
        result = result and text.count(character) == frequency
    return result



def filter_words_better(text: str, filters: list) -> bool:
    """ This answer is from Kelly Bundy in the comments below
    This is the better answer, and easier to read
    """
    for character, frequency in filters:
        if text.count(character) != frequency:
            return False
    return True


wordlist = ["bbad", "bbaad", "bxab"]


filters = [
    ("a", 1),
    ("b", 2)
]


for word in wordlist:
    print(f"{word} -> {filter_words(word, filters)}")

print('-----')

for word in wordlist:
    print(f"{word} -> {filter_words_better(word, filters)}")
```

**output**

```
bbad -> True
bbaad -> False
bxab -> True
-----
bbad -> True
bbaad -> False
bxab -> True
```

Comment: [Two variations](https://tio.run/##nY9BCsIwEEX3OcW4a0DduJFAXXoC9xLTCQ2EpE4maE8fWyltBRfiXw7vf950PbcxHI4dldKgBes8I10fkZpUMT5ZQWLaTvekwLvEEnYnuMXolYAhNhKYVpM2AzKghPeMwfTgwtx7g2OchXF2b2IOXM01CZt6aS74GELOFOCsfUKxOlwooxD/Wk8j2vvqu1C9Evrw@e1lWcoL).

Comment: thanks for that comment edit. I was wondering what was not pythonic about it (besides stupidly obfuscating the `filter` keyword)

Comment: I had noticed shadowing `filter`, but what I really meant was not unpacking the items into two meaningful variables, instead later accessing them with `[0]` and `[1]`. And while your `and` does short-circuit, it only avoids pointless further countings. It still goes through the remaining filters, instead of returning `False` right away. (That's what I meant with short**er**-circuit.)

Comment: yeah I understood both after looking at your code. I keep forgetting the unpacking bit. DIdn't want to edit my suggestion as I don't want to take credit for what you did.

Comment: I ended up implementing @KellyBundy variation. I'm not set on regex I just thought it would be faster for some reason which is important because I'm using this filter a lot. Thanks for the help, appreciate it!

Comment: If there were several letters to check for it would be faster to construct a hash whose keys were the unique letters of the word and whose values were the number of times the key appeared in the word. Suppose the word were `'hippopotamus'`.  In Ruby `h = 'hippopotamus'.each_char.tally #=> {"h"=>1, "i"=>1, "p"=>3, "o"=>2, "t"=>1, "a"=>1, "m"=>1, "u"=>1, "s"=>1}`. It is then a simple matter to check whether all specified letters have the correct count. Note that the production of this hash for a word `w` is O(`w.length`).

Comment: @CarySwoveland Depends. With just "several" letters, repeated `str.count` is probably faster already for short strings.

Comment: @Kelly, conjecture alert! Suppose the word had `n` characters and `m` letters were to be counted. Brute force is O(n*m). In Ruby having `tally` written in C makes the O(n) construction of the hash very fast, and since hash lookups are almost O(1) it would move right along. (Of course I cannot disagree if, say, `n = 3` and `m = 1`. :-)). Does Python have a method equivalent to Ruby's `tally`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland conjecture alert squared! :-). I don't know much Ruby, so tell me if I did something wrong, but in [my test](https://replit.com/@KellyBundy/CharCount#main.rb), one `tally` was around **100x slower** than five `count`. Still think `tally` is "very fast"? Plus, the individual character counting could be stopped as soon as one doesn't have the desired result.

Comment: @Kelly, Let's say the word were 'pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis' and it were required that there were two `'p'`'s, four `'n'`'s, one `'e'`... OK, I yield! I forgot about the short-circuiting property of the brute-force method, which is a killer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Unclear what your "..." means. But I added another test to my linked script, where I individually count all 26 letters of the alphabet in a long string, and that's still about 16 times faster than a single `tally`. And that's not even including that short-circuiting. `tally` is just super slow in comparison.

Comment: @Kelly, "..." means, "I concede!". However, use of the `tally` was more than twice as fast as brute-force in one test I did. I constructed a string containing 2600 characters, 100 of each letter of the alphabet and tested that each letter appeared 100 times, so, aside from the short-circuit considerations, `tally` might be good for *really, really, really* long words.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Ah, I thought "and these further letters". In which case, if shown completely, I would've tried it. Please show that test you just described, I can't reproduce it. For me, `tally` remains many times slower.

Comment: @Kelly, let's [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242503/count-letters-in-a-word).

Answer (score 1):

One could use the following regular expression (which could be constructed programmatically) to match words that contain exactly one `'a'` and two `'b'`'s.

```
\b(?=[^b]*(?:b[^b]*){2}\b)(?=[^a]*a[^a]*\b)\w*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mlGqXF/1)

If it were required that the word contained three `'b'`'s, rather than two, one would change `{2}` to `{3}`.

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
\b            # match a word boundary
(?=           # begin a positive lookahead
  [^b]*       # match >= 0 chars other than 'b'
  (?:b[^b]*)  # match 'b' followed by >= 0 chars other than 'b' in
              # a non-capture group
  {2}         # execute the non-capture group twice
  \b          # match a word boundary
)             # end positive lookahead
(?=           # begin a positive lookahead
  [^a]*       # match >= 0 chars other than 'a'
  a           # match 'a'
  [^a]*       # match >= 0 chars other than 'a'
  \b          # match a word boundary
)             # end positive lookahead
\w*           # match >= 0 word chars
```

Comment: Another idea could be to turn the second lookahead into a match `\b(?=[^\sb]*(?:b[^\sb]*){2}\b)[^a\s]*a[^a\s]*\b` https://regex101.com/r/oju24p/1

Comment: @The big blue bird, true and thanks. I did it that way to suggest how it would be extended if there were more letters to check, but it's a good point that one could be a match rather than a lookahead.